# GAM MGCV: Difference in fitting and summary

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Hello I am trying to adjust a GAM in R.I am trying to see the relationship that can exist through time in 57 river stations that are divided into Impacted and not previously Impacted. There are several variables to measure Wtemp, pH, TN, DOconc, which are nutrients that are evaluated in each of these river stations. I have this information in summary

I am taking the rivers as the individual and therefore as a random effect along with its interaction for the year. So fit the following model in R:

```
M1 = gam(DOconc ~  Impacto +s(Year, bs="ps") +s(Year, by=Impacto,m =1 ,bs="ps")+ s(Stnumber,bs="re")+s(Year,Stnumber,bs="re"), data = X)

summary(M1)
> summary(M7)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
DOconc ~ Impacto + s(Year, bs = "ps") + s(Year, by = Impacto, 
    bs = "ps") + s(Stnumber, bs = "re") + s(Year, 
    Stnumber, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    6.446     25.076   0.257    0.797
ImpactoN       1.031     31.719   0.032    0.974

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                     edf  Ref.df         F p-value    
s(Year)           8.0125  8.4665 6.431e+01 < 2e-16 ***
s(Year):ImpactoI  3.8747  4.6776 4.447e+00 0.00157 ** 
s(Year):ImpactoN  0.6667  0.6667 3.730e+00 0.11483    
s(Stnumber)      50.5310 54.0000 1.334e+11 < 2e-16 ***
s(Year,Stnumber) 51.4611 54.0000 9.713e+10 < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rank: 140/141
R-sq.(adj) =  0.477   Deviance explained = 48.2%
GCV = 2.1151  Scale est. = 2.0926    n = 10952
```

but I got a doubt when I make a mistake when writing it and use the “by” in the smooth function where the random interaction goes.

```
M8 = gam(DOconc ~  Impacto + s(Year, bs= "ps") + s(Year, by= Impacto) +s(Stnumber, bs="re")+s(Year,by=Stnumber, bs="re"), data = X)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
DOconc ~ Impacto + s(Year, bs = "ps") + s(Year, by = Impacto) + 
    s(Stnumber, bs = "re") + s(Year, by = Stnumber, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    9.096     39.669   0.229    0.819
ImpactoN       4.501     50.154   0.090    0.928

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                               edf Ref.df         F  p-value    
s(Year)                  8.033e+00  8.070 2.068e+01  < 2e-16 ***
s(Year):ImpactoI         8.964e+00  8.965 2.660e+01  < 2e-16 ***
s(Year):ImpactoN         8.953e+00  8.964 2.830e+01  < 2e-16 ***
s(Stnumber)              5.385e+01 54.000 1.985e+09  < 2e-16 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50010500 4.086e-01  1.000 1.565e+04 0.088906 .  
s(Year):Stnumber50011000 9.898e-01  1.000 2.048e+06 2.98e-15 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50011400 6.167e-01  1.000 3.111e+05 1.11e-09 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50020500 3.291e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.954567    
s(Year):Stnumber50025000 4.215e-01  1.000 1.149e+04 0.147556    
s(Year):Stnumber50026050 2.217e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.906029    
s(Year):Stnumber50027250 3.254e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.612759    
s(Year):Stnumber50028000 4.354e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.587727    
s(Year):Stnumber50029000 4.983e-01  1.000 2.273e+04 0.040388 *  
s(Year):Stnumber50030700 3.826e-01  1.000 4.095e+04 0.003523 ** 
s(Year):Stnumber50031200 3.622e-01  1.000 8.233e+03 0.213019    
s(Year):Stnumber50035500 3.150e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.942086    
s(Year):Stnumber50035950 3.982e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.784416    
s(Year):Stnumber50038100 5.115e-01  1.000 4.442e+04 0.005809 ** 
s(Year):Stnumber50038200 5.043e-01  1.000 2.085e+05 3.53e-08 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50038320 2.506e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.489716    
s(Year):Stnumber50039500 4.599e-01  1.000 2.393e+04 0.036194 *  
s(Year):Stnumber50043000 4.325e-01  1.000 7.221e+04 0.000104 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50044850 3.744e-01  1.000 1.495e+05 1.26e-08 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50046000 4.860e-01  1.000 1.337e+05 4.16e-07 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50047537 4.898e-07  1.000 0.000e+00 0.564396    
s(Year):Stnumber50047600 3.868e-01  1.000 7.331e+03 0.230251    
s(Year):Stnumber50047990 4.397e-01  1.000 7.006e+04 0.000187 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50048510 4.872e-01  1.000 9.709e+04 7.22e-05 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50048800 4.457e-01  1.000 1.603e+05 7.45e-08 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50049100 6.482e-01  1.000 5.976e+05 9.44e-15 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50050300 4.132e-01  1.000 4.623e+05  < 2e-16 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50055000 4.993e-01  1.000 1.661e+05 5.65e-08 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50055250 4.614e-01  1.000 4.075e+05  < 2e-16 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50055400 3.064e-01  1.000 1.807e+04 0.048259 *  
s(Year):Stnumber50057025 3.959e-01  1.000 2.036e+04 0.043402 *  
s(Year):Stnumber50059100 3.171e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.375655    
s(Year):Stnumber50063800 4.577e-01  1.000 1.464e+04 0.111869    
s(Year):Stnumber50071000 3.240e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.697025    
s(Year):Stnumber50072500 4.352e-01  1.000 2.635e+04 0.023058 *  
s(Year):Stnumber50082000 4.813e-01  1.000 4.934e+04 0.002513 ** 
s(Year):Stnumber50083500 2.250e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.466933    
s(Year):Stnumber50086500 3.360e-01  1.000 7.997e+04 0.000140 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50091000 4.719e-01  1.000 2.856e+04 0.025685 *  
s(Year):Stnumber50091800 3.565e-01  1.000 4.531e+04 0.007412 ** 
s(Year):Stnumber50092000 4.836e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.500223    
s(Year):Stnumber50106500 4.104e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.693525    
s(Year):Stnumber50114000 2.869e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.703911    
s(Year):Stnumber50115000 2.913e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.605848    
s(Year):Stnumber50116200 4.128e-01  1.000 3.161e+04 0.014741 *  
s(Year):Stnumber50124700 4.597e-01  1.000 4.774e+04 0.002934 ** 
s(Year):Stnumber50129700 4.991e-01  1.000 2.263e+05 4.35e-05 ***
s(Year):Stnumber50133600 3.272e-01  1.000 4.209e+04 0.002412 ** 
s(Year):Stnumber50136400 2.302e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.437248    
s(Year):Stnumber50138000 4.202e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.677562    
s(Year):Stnumber50138800 2.443e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.611650    
s(Year):Stnumber50143000 3.266e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.880337    
s(Year):Stnumber50144000 4.383e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.575126    
s(Year):Stnumber50146000 3.185e-05  1.000 0.000e+00 0.862582    
s(Year):Stnumber50147600 3.497e-01  1.000 2.494e+04 0.029534 *  
s(Year):Stnumber50149100 4.805e-01  1.000 7.192e+04 0.000188 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rank: 140/141
R-sq.(adj) =  0.485   Deviance explained =   49%
GCV = 2.0786  Scale est. = 2.0601    n = 10952
```

Here I see all the rivers crunched for the year but I don't know what the difference is between model 1 and model 2. And in this case which one I should use.

On the other hand, I do not understand why if it is a random effect, a test appears for the significance of said effect.

Comment: Please do no post pictures of model output. The site supports excellent rendering of code and output if you enclose each block with three backticks ``` (one set of ``` at the start and one at the end.

Comment: ok sorry, I don't know how to add R content directly.

Comment: I've literally just told you how to do it in my comment above.